# Symfony3 routing controllers

Tags: php, symfony

Hello I've got a problem with my routing.

I have my normal Appbundle full of controllers for users and admins. I don't want to separate all my controllers to another bundle.

So my plan was to create another subdirectory in my AppBundle which looks like this.

```
src/AppBundle/Controller/Admin/Admincontroller

src/AppBundle/Controller/User/UserController
```

In my routing.yml I created the link like this (also tried different options)

```
test:
path: /test
defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Admin/TestController:test }
```

But I am still getting routing problems.

Also creating the route in my controller is not possible.

My namespace looks like this

```
namespace AppBundle\Admin\Controller;
```

So I am not really sure what is wrong with my routing, and why my controllers are not recognized by Symfony. In the normal directory everything works normal though.

[image]

My Error message

```
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException: "Class AppBundle\Admin\Controller\TestController does not exist in C:\Users\ylamb\Documents\dev\db-yl\src\AppBundle/Controller/ (which is being imported from "C:\Users\ylamb\Documents\dev\db-yl\app/config\routing.yml")." at C:\Users\ylamb\Documents\dev\db-yl\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\FileLoader.php line 118
```

Comment: what `AppBundle\cursussen:Admin:cursus` should be?

Comment: AppBundle:Admin/Admincontroller:cursus should do the trick.  If not, update your question with the error message.  Or maybe your question is wrong.  Do you actually have AppBundle/Admin/Controller/SomeControler.php?

Comment: i edited my original post with more information

Comment: AppBundle\Admin\Controller\TestController should be AppBundle\Controller\Admin\TestController See the difference?  Needs to match your directory structure.

Comment: I can see the difference, but where is it going wrong? In my routing or some where else?

Comment: The namespace in your controller file is wrong.  Your updated route looks right however the error message you showed does not match your routing.  Delete your cache, take a deep breath and then recheck your code to make sure it is consistent.  I suspect you have gotten into the "try anything and hope it works" mode of development.  Maybe take a break.

Comment: I got it working now, i totaly underestimated the use of the name space.. My routing `test:
   path:     /test
   defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Admin/Test:test}` and my namespace is like this `namespace AppBundle\Controller\Admin;
` And indeed time for a break :)

Answer (score 0):

The `Controller` suffix should not be used when using the `Bundle:Controller:action` format:

```
test:
    path: /test
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Admin/Test:test }
```

---

Fyi, you can also just use the normal `FQCN::method` syntax in your routing. This would avoid "magic" and confusing situations like this:

```
test:
    path: /test
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle\Controller\Admin\TestController::testAction }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have incorrect namespace in your controller:

```
namespace AppBundle\Admin\Controller;
```

It's placed under path:

```
AppBundle\Controller\Admin\TestController.php
```

so it should be

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller\Admin;
```

Or alternatively leave the namespace, but organize your directories the other way.